# Mac App Store consumable receipts have empty in_app hash on server side validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store, mac-app-store

I verify the receipt of in-app-purchases (so called consumables) for the Mac App Store on the server side. The response from Apple's servers usually looks like this:

```
    { 
      "status"=>0, 
      "environment"=>"Production", 
      "receipt" => 
        { 
          "receipt_type" => "Production", 
          "adam_id"=>410628904, 
          "bundle_id" => "com.company.product", 
          "application_version"=>"1.0.0", 
          "download_id"=>002141541230420, 
          "request_date"=>"2013-10-22 07:53:11 Etc/GMT", 
          "request_date_ms"=>"1382428391914", 
          "request_date_pst"=>"2013-10-22 00:53:11 America/Los_Angeles", 
          "original_purchase_date"=>"2011-08-22 06:05:47 Etc/GMT", 
          "original_purchase_date_ms"=>"1313993147000", 
          "original_purchase_date_pst"=>"2011-08-21 23:05:47 America/Los_Angeles", 
          "original_application_version"=>"1.0.0", 
          "in_app"=> [
            {
              "quantity"=>"1", 
              "product_id"=>"com.company.product.mac_consumable", 
              "transaction_id"=>"9123912391231", 
              "original_transaction_id"=>"51881235936908", 
              "purchase_date"=>"2013-10-22 07:52:06 Etc/GMT", 
              "purchase_date_ms"=>"1382428326000", 
              "purchase_date_pst"=>"2013-10-22 00:52:06 America/Los_Angeles", 
              "original_purchase_date"=>"2013-10-22 07:52:06 Etc/GMT", 
              "original_purchase_date_ms"=>"1382428326000", 
              "original_purchase_date_pst"=>"2013-10-22 00:52:06 America/Los_Angeles", 
              "bundle_id"=>"com.company.product"
              }
         ]
      }
    }
```

But sometimes we get back information without the in_app hash set:

```
    { 
      "status"=>0, 
      "environment"=>"Production", 
      "receipt" => 
        { 
          "receipt_type" => "Production", 
          "adam_id"=>312621904, 
          "bundle_id" => "com.company.product", 
          "application_version"=>"1.0.0", 
          "download_id"=>002141541230420, 
          "request_date"=>"2013-10-22 07:53:11 Etc/GMT", 
          "request_date_ms"=>"1382428391914", 
          "request_date_pst"=>"2013-10-22 00:53:11 America/Los_Angeles", 
          "original_purchase_date"=>"2011-08-22 06:05:47 Etc/GMT", 
          "original_purchase_date_ms"=>"1313993147000", 
          "original_purchase_date_pst"=>"2011-08-21 23:05:47 America/Los_Angeles", 
          "original_application_version"=>"1.0.0", 
          "in_app"=> []
      }
    }
```

Does this mean the receipts are invalid? Should the in_app field always be populated? Or should those receipts be considered valid as well and why is the in_app information empty then?

Comment: I have the same issue! I need to know what happened! Could it be that the transaction was denied apple side? Should I show a message? My account does not seem to get credited when this happens.

Answer (score 3):

***Does this mean the receipts are invalid?***

No, the `status` value is `0`, which according to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) means that the receipt is valid. It just doesn't contain any in-app purchase “sub-receipts”.

***Should the in_app field always be populated?***

No, it's possible for a receipt to not contain any in-app purchases.

---

So apparently your problem is that for some reason the receipt your app is sending to your backend doesn't contain information for an in-app purchase, even though you expect it to.

When an in-app purchase transaction enters the "purchased" state, the receipt should be up to date on the client device — you should ensure that you don't try to send the receipt onto your server before this happens.

One other thing to consider trying is `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` (only available since 10.9, though) — in some edge conditions the receipt might not be up to date, and you'd need to wait for it to update before sending the receipt redemption request to your backend.

Comment: We do not get any cash for these empty receipts from apple, so clearly these orders did not go thru on apples side. I would still like to be able to reproduce this case, as it might be interesting for us to track. Could it be invalid credit card details or insufficient funds?

Comment: @Steeve17 We have the same problem. Have you been able to understand exactly what happens when "in_app\":[]? Would be very grateful for any hint.